# Spring-data-cassandra 1.3.4 not compatible with Cassandra 3.x

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I have tried using Spring-data-cassandra 1.3.4 along with the latest cassandra-driver-core : 3.0.0  On Cassandra 2.1.12 (which comes as part of DSE 4.8.4) and everything works fine. Where as same spring batch doesn't work with the plain Cassandra 3.x versions. I tried it out on Cassandra 3.2,3.3 & 3.4.

I get the `ClassNotFound Exception` which is mentioned in the below stack trace.

Now I totally understand that this is due to a particular method(asJavaClass) not being present in "com.datastax.driver.core.DataType.java".

My question is is there any alternative way to get around this?

I am using the Spring Batch to do one time data load which is huge. And I cannot use anything less than Cassandra 3.3.

```
2016-04-11 13:38:32.684  WARN 3166 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingContext' defined in class path resource [com/walgreens/batch/config/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext]: Factory method 'mappingContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.DataType.asJavaClass()Ljava/lang/Class;
2016-04-11 13:38:32.808 ERROR 3166 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingContext' defined in class path resource [com/walgreens/batch/config/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext]: Factory method 'mappingContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.DataType.asJavaClass()Ljava/lang/Class;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.walgreens.batch.WagStoreInventoryBatchJobApplication.main(WagStoreInventoryBatchJobApplication.java:43) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraMappingContext]: Factory method 'mappingContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.DataType.asJavaClass()Ljava/lang/Class;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.DataType.asJavaClass()Ljava/lang/Class;
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.CassandraSimpleTypeHolder.<clinit>(CassandraSimpleTypeHolder.java:62) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.BasicCassandraMappingContext.<init>(BasicCassandraMappingContext.java:73) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.walgreens.batch.config.CassandraConfiguration.mappingContext(CassandraConfiguration.java:47) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.walgreens.batch.config.CassandraConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$78a36265.CGLIB$mappingContext$4(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.walgreens.batch.config.CassandraConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$78a36265$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c7f2ad2a.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:355) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.walgreens.batch.config.CassandraConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$78a36265.mappingContext(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted

2016-04-11 13:38:32.811  INFO 3166 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/Users/Siraj/Documents/workspace/Ask2/WagStoreInventoryBatchJob/target/classes/, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-batch/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-batch-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.5/logback-classic-1.1.5.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.5/logback-core-1.1.5.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.16/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.16/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.3.3/hsqldb-2.3.3.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-core/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-batch-core-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/com/ibm/jbatch/com.ibm.jbatch-tck-spi/1.0/com.ibm.jbatch-tck-spi-1.0.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/javax/batch/javax.batch-api/1.0/javax.batch-api-1.0.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.7/xstream-1.4.7.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/xmlpull/xmlpull/1.1.3.1/xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.4c/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jettison/jettison/1.2/jettison-1.2.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-infrastructure/3.0.6.RELEASE/spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/springframework/retry/spring-retry/1.1.2.RELEASE/spring-retry-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-cassandra/1.3.4.RELEASE/spring-data-cassandra-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-cql/1.3.4.RELEASE/spring-cql-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.11.4.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/com/datastax/cassandra/cassandra-driver-dse/2.1.9/cassandra-driver-dse-2.1.9.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.16/slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.16/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.0.32/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.32/tomcat-juli-8.0.32.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/com/datastax/cassandra/cassandra-driver-core/3.0.0/cassandra-driver-core-3.0.0.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-handler/4.0.33.Final/netty-handler-4.0.33.Final.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-buffer/4.0.33.Final/netty-buffer-4.0.33.Final.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-common/4.0.33.Final/netty-common-4.0.33.Final.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport/4.0.33.Final/netty-transport-4.0.33.Final.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec/4.0.33.Final/netty-codec-4.0.33.Final.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/16.0.1/guava-16.0.1.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-core/3.1.2/metrics-core-3.1.2.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.8.2/joda-time-2.8.2.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-configuration-processor/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-configuration-processor-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/json/json/20140107/json-20140107.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.8/aspectjweaver-1.8.8.jar, file:/Users/Siraj/.m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0.4/ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar]
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what your implementation looks like using Spring-Batch along with Spring-Data-Cassandra (hard to say since these frameworks will make the inner workings a bit opaque as Aaron has mentioned). However for "batch" loading in Cassandra this article is a [must read](https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/08/28/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword/)

Comment: Spring Data Cassandra 1.5 is released which internally uses Cassandra java driver 3.1.3

Answer (score 2):

Spring-Data-Cassandra 1.3.4 (and even the newest dev version) uses the client driver [Cassandra 2.1.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/master/pom.xml#L37) see Datastax driver [compatibility chart](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/driver-matrix/doc/common/driverMatrix.html?scroll=driverMatrix__java-driver-matrix) and you'll see that you need the 3.x client driver to use Cassandra 3.x .

And as Aaron has mentioned isn't the best ORM implementation for C* since it was initially designed for a RDBMS interface first, thus has implementations that are anti-patterns for NoSQL databases like Cassandra.

You mentioned that this is a one-time data load of a bulk of data, I would first read about the best way to load lots of data into [Cassandra from this article](https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/08/28/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword/) (hint DO NOT USE batches). I don't know of any really good tools out there to do some data migration out of the box (depends on what your source system is too). So you'll probably have to write something custom, or adapt something.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is one of the risks you take when you opt to use a framework driver instead of an [approved DataStax Driver](http://www.planetcassandra.org/apache-cassandra-client-drivers/).

If you want to be using a cutting-edge version of Cassandra, then to **ensure your highest chances for deploying a successful application** you should also use the DataStax Java Driver (in your case).

Additionally, there are two other reasons as to why you may want to reconsider using spring-cassandra-data:

- When you call `insert(List<T> entities, WriteOptions options)` (and related methods) spring-data-cassandra runs a **CQL BATCH INSERT** behind-the-scenes.  This particular use of batch inserts is a known anti-pattern in Cassandra, and can endanger the stability of your cluster.
- When paging through many rows, spring-data-cassandra will run a `COUNT(*)` behind-the-scenes.  This is a horribly inefficient query to run on a cluster with many nodes.  It will be slow and potentially time-out on larger tables.

As I always say, you cannot go wrong by choosing a DataStax-approved driver.

Comment: While everything you said above is correct, don't forget that using a native driver means you are hard-coding your application to one database.   Spring Data makes your code more portable, at the expense of the full functionality of a native driver.   Pick your poison.  :)

Answer (score 0):

> nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.DataType.asJavaClass()Ljava/lang/Class; 2016-04-11 13:38:32.808

Maybe the version of the Java driver used by Spring Batch is not using the latest (3.0.0)

Comment: Yeah they are still using Datastax Java Client Driver [2.1.7.1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/master/pom.xml#L37)

Comment: SO this is your problem, need to upgrade Spring Batch to a version that supports 3.0.0 driver. You can try to monkey patch and force the driver version in the pom.xml but it may nor work.

Comment: Spring Data Cassandra still uses the 2.x driver. We have plans to upgrade to 3.0 in the near future.