# Cassandra 3.5 compatablity with spring data 1.4

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data, cassandra-3.0

Please tell me whether I can use `Spring data 1.4` with `cassandra 3.5` ?
if not then suggest which ORM I can use ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36558099/spring-data-cassandra-1-3-4-not-compatible-with-cassandra-3-x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't

Spring Data Cassandra version 1.4.1 is pulling Cassandra version 2.1.11 (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/spring-data-cassandra-parent/1.4.1.RELEASE/spring-data-cassandra-parent-1.4.1.RELEASE.pom)

If you want an object mapper for Cassandra 3.5 :

- the default object mapper of the java driver : https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/tree/3.0/manual/object_mapper/using
- Achilles 5.2.0 (http://doanduyhai.github.io/Achilles/)

Edit: Spring Data Cassandra 1.5 has just been released and now support Java driver 3.1.3

Comment: Thanks for prompt response

Comment: Spring Data Cassandra 1.5 will use the Cassandra 3.0 driver and restore access to newer Cassandra versions.

Comment: Spring Data Cassandra 1.5 is released which internally uses Cassandra java driver 3.1.3